# Variables from php GET in jquery slider

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-slider

A GET of url params is echoed into three divs, and I want to use those values in this function

```
$(window).load(function(){
var theMax = document.getElementById("maxy").innerHTML;    
var theStart = document.getElementById("starty").innerHTML;    
var theEnd = document.getElementById("endy").innerHTML;      

    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true, min: 0, max: [theMax], values: [
         theStart, theEnd], slide: slideTime, change: checkMax
    });
```

The rest of the script is intended partly to put the scrubber handles at the specified start and end positions.  But both sliders just go to theMax value.

I can alert out the vars correctly.

If I echo the values right inside the script it works.

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true, min: 0, max: [<?php echo "$max";?>], values: [

         <?php if (isset($_GET['startparam']))
{
echo "$start";
}
else {
echo "0"; } ?>, 

<?php if (isset($_GET['endparam']))
{
echo "$end";
}
else {
echo "$max"; } ?>], slide: slideTime, change: checkMax
    });
```

Since I can alert out the vars, and since theMax value seems to be getting used,  is it just a matter of syntax for the other two vars?  Or if not, should I restructure with ajax, or would it be better to use something like getParameterByName to get the params into the script?

Comment: You're mixing document.getElementById in with jQuery, you should really stick to one method. You don't need to put values in divs then use innerHtml to get them, just set them in javascript.

Comment: @Popnoodles You mean like var myVar = "<?php echo $php_var; ?>"; ?

Comment: That'll do the trick.

Comment: In that case, would it not be ok to put the php inside the function as in my example above?  That way I could include the php conditional statement for when there is no param.

Comment: If you're outputting everything including the JS with PHP then put it where you like as long as the generated code validates.

Comment: No complaints from console, so I suppose that's what I'll do.  I guess I just feel a sort of primitive, uncomprehending fear when the php tags become the same color as the js vars in my editor.